# Wagtail Admin: Dynamic Choicefield

Tags: python, wagtail

I have a very interesting task.

In Wagtail Admin we create a new page of **products**. Here we specify of course the *title*, *choicefield1* and *choicefield2*. The *choicefield1* is group of types and *choicefield2* is a group of values for each value in *choicefield1*.

What I need is, when selecting something from *choicefield1*, dynamic show only the values in *choicefield2* that are in the group selected in *choicefield1*, instead of displaying all groups.

Also transform [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSG2k.png) to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw2SD.png).
Images are just for example, but I need this in Wagtail Admin, when creating new page.

How is this possible?

Comment: Could you display your relevant models.py code please?

Answer (score 1):

If the field is located in a block you could specify a custom template for it. In this template you could write a javascript which converts the FULL select with `<optgroup>` elements to 2 selects of which the first lists the `<optgroup>` labels and the second only displays the associated `<option>` elements.

For pages you could simply use [a hook](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-js) to add javascript to the interface and modify the select.

See [the documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html#custom-editing-interfaces-for-structblock) for more information on how to customise a `StructBlock`.